# The script works for sometime and the crashes

Tags: python-3.x, binance-api-client

This script runs for like may be 10 seconds(It varies) and then suddenly stops with an error saying

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

```
from binance.client import Client
client = Client()

coin = "PYRBUSD"
ST = 20
LT = 60

def gethistoricals(symbol, LT):
    df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, '1m', str(LT) + 'minutes ago UTC'))
    closes = pd.DataFrame(df[4])
    closes.columns = ['Close']    
    closes['ST'] = closes.Close.rolling(ST).sum() 
    closes.dropna(inplace=True)
    return closes

def check(coin): 
    ma1 = round((float(historicals['ST'].values[0]) / ST), 4)
    
    print(ma1)
    print(type(ma1))
    return True

while True:
    historicals = gethistoricals(coin, 20) 
    print(historicals)

    if check(coin): 
        print("Check Pass")
```

My output looks like this. Please note the `Index: []` at the end

```
.
.
.

Close     ST
19  4.43000000  88.72
4.436
<class 'float'>
Check Pass
         Close     ST
19  4.43000000  88.72
4.436
<class 'float'>
Check Pass
         Close     ST
19  4.43000000  88.72
4.436
<class 'float'>
Check Pass
         Close     ST
19  4.43000000  88.72
4.436
<class 'float'>
Check Pass
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Close, ST]
Index: []
```

I am getting this error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 23>()
     24 historicals = gethistoricals(coin, 20) 
     25 print(historicals)
---> 27 if check(coin): 
     28     print("Check Pass")

Input In [7], in check(coin)
     16 def check(coin): 
---> 17     ma1 = round((float(historicals['ST'].values[0]) / ST), 4)
     19     print(ma1)
     20     print(type(ma1))

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: you always access index 0 of `historicals['ST'].values` and sometimes it's just empty so you should check that and handle this case

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thank you. What you suggested worked. What could be the reason for sometimes for it to be empty ?

Comment: I don't know in this particular case but it's something to always expect when you're dealing with external resources like on the web. You would have to check with their API or documentation.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thank you very much. I was struggling with this for a long time and your code helped me to solve it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check before you access a value:

```py
def check(coin): 
    if historicals.empty:
        return False

    ma1 = round((float(historicals['ST'].values[0]) / ST), 4)    
    print(ma1)
    print(type(ma1))
    return True
```